# Execute a command in a new named screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I have a script that creates a new screen and executes a command (dev webserver) in it.

```
screen -S webserver -dm sh launch_webserver.sh
```

However, when the command is done (or webserver quits), the screen is destroyed. How can I avoid that ?

Comment: Put the commands in your launch_webserver.sh script between a 'while :; do mycommands; done' ?

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to happen when the command is finished? The screen session ends when there are no more running commands, so if you want to keep the session around, you'll have to run another command.

If you want to keep the window around and run more commands it it, run a shell when the initial command finishes.

```
screen -S webserver -dm sh -c 'launch_webserver.sh; echo $?; exec bash -i'
```

If you want to keep the window around just to see the output, run a command that waits, such as `sleep` (with a near-infinite argument) or `read` (waits until you press <kbd>Enter</kbd>).

```
screen -S webserver -dm sh -c 'launch_webserver.sh; echo $?; read'
```

If you want to keep the session around but not the window, run another command. You'll have to write a screenrc file (which is a good idea anyway).

```
screen -c /path/to/webserver.screenrc
```

where `/path/to/webserver.screenrc` contains

```
sessionname webserver
screen -t webserver launch_webserver.sh
screen -t shell bash
```